# How to rigorously prove that the toric code ground state has non-trivial topological order?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, mathematical-physics, topological-order

Consider the unique ground state $|\psi\rangle$ of [Kitaev's toric code model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toric_code) on a sphere. Has it been rigorously proved that $|\psi\rangle$ cannot be transformed into a trivial product state by **ANY** local unitary transformation?

This might seem obvious for physicists, as there are lots of non-trivial behavior of toric code model distinct from symmetry breaking phases. But when it comes to rigorous proof, it seems hard to rule out all possible local unitary transformations. So could it be proved rigorously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this paper answers the question in a rigorous manner: https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.2926